# Handling Concurrent Access Errors in EF Core with MySql

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

I am building a Windows MAUI app that tries to access a database collection via api (GraphQL, HotChocolate), every five seconds. Basically it tries to get the latest item by its Index field, which happens to be the primary field as well. Sometimes it works, but most of the times it fails.

**Here's the code that fails:**

```cs
public async Task<List<ChangeSetModel>> TakeLastAsync(int count)
{
    List<long> lastChangeSetIndices = null!;
    try
    {

        lastChangeSetIndices = await _dbContext.ChangeSets
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.ChangeSetIndex)
            .Select(c => c.ChangeSetIndex)
            .Take(count)
            .ToListAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        throw;
    }
    ...
}
```

#### This seemingly randomly produces either of these two errors:

1. "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: server=host;port=3306;database=db;user id=user;password=pwd". The Key's value is set to my connection string, I don't have any code adding connection strings anywhere, it's only used in db context instantiation, though some suggest it might have something to do with how EF Core caches connections etc.
2. "Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct."

---

When I asked around, people says that EF Core is designed to handle concurrent requests and this kind of thing should never happen, I don't know where to go, and how to debug this issue further.

I tried to change the way I instantiate the database, it's lifetime etc - nothing helped so far.

Any advice and idea is much appreciated. Thank you!

---

### Here's more context:

The front app is a MAUI + Blazor windows native app, .NET 7.
It makes requests via GraphQL to my backend app, which is a HotChocolate GraphQL implementation, also .NET 7.

The database is an innodb on **MySQL** Server 8

**SqlContext.cs:**

```cs
public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
    public SqlContext() { }
    public SqlContext(DbContextOptions<SqlContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    ...
    public virtual DbSet<SqlChangeSet> ChangeSets { get; set; }
    ...
```

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SqlChangeSet>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ChangeSetIndex).HasName("PRIMARY");

        entity.ToTable("changesets");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "fk_changesets_user_id_idx");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.ChangeSetId, "fk_changesets_id_idx");

        entity.Property(e => e.ChangeSetIndex)
            .HasColumnName("changeset_index");

        entity.Property(e => e.ChangeSetId)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .HasColumnName("changeset_id");

        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("created_at");

        entity.Property(e => e.Operation)
            .HasColumnName("operation");
        entity.Property(e => e.RecordChanges)
            .HasColumnType("text")
            .HasColumnName("record_changes");
        entity.Property(e => e.RecordId)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .HasColumnName("record_id");
        entity.Property(e => e.RecordType).HasColumnName("record_type");
        entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .HasColumnName("user_id")
            .UseCollation("utf8mb3_general_ci")
            .HasCharSet("utf8mb3");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.ChangeSets)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("fk_changesets_user_id");
    });
```

**SqlChangeSet.cs**

```cs
[Serializable]
[JsonObject("changeSet")]
public class SqlChangeSet : IChangeSetEntity
{
    public long ChangeSetIndex { get; set; }
    public string ChangeSetId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Operation { get; set; }
    public string RecordId { get; set; } = null!;
    public int RecordType { get; set; }
    public string? RecordChanges { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual SqlUser User { get; set; } = null!;

    public static IChangeSetEntity FromDto(ChangeSetDto entity)
    {
        return new SqlChangeSet()
        {
            ChangeSetIndex = entity.ChangeSetIndex,
            ChangeSetId = entity.ChangeSetId,
            UserId = entity.UserId,
            Operation = (int)entity.Operation,
            RecordType = (int)entity.RecordType,
            RecordId = entity.RecordId,
            RecordChanges = entity.RecordChanges,
            CreatedAt = entity.CreatedAt,
        };
    }
}
```

**Query.cs**

```cs
public class Query
{
    private readonly IDataProvider _dataProvider;

    public Query(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
    
    ...

    public async Task<RequestResult> TakeLastAsync(string recordTypeName, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            using var unitOfWork = (SqlUnitOfWork)_dataProvider.CreateUnitOfWork();

            object? dtos = null;
            var recordType = (RecordType)Enum.Parse(typeof(RecordType), recordTypeName);

            switch (recordType)
            {
                case RecordType.ChangeSet:

                    List<ChangeSetModel> changeSets = null!;
                    changeSets = await unitOfWork.ChangeSets.TakeLastAsync(count);

                    dtos = changeSets.Select(ChangeSetDto.FromModel);

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return new RequestResult()
            {
                Success = true,
                SerializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtos)
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new RequestResult()
            {
                Success = false,
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message,
                SerializedData = string.Empty
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RemoteDatabase");
        var signingSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiJwtSigningKey");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(signingSecret))
        {
            throw new Exception("Connection string is not set");
        }

        builder.Services.AddTransient<IDataProvider, SqlDataProvider>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<EmailService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<FileService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ExceptionHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<PasswordResetResolver>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<UpdatePasswordResolver>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<RegisterUserResolver>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ConfirmEmailResolver>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<LoginResolver>();


        builder.Services.AddLocalization();

        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingSecret));

        builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters =
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = "https://auth.chillicream.com",
                    ValidAudience = "https://graphql.chillicream.com",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey
                };
        });

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

        builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddQueryType<Query>()
            .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
            .AddProjections()
            .AddFiltering()
            .AddSorting();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();
        app.MapGraphQL("/graphql");
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

**SqlDataProvider.cs**

```
    public class SqlDataProvider : IDataProvider
    {
        public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }

        public event Action? DatabaseInitialized;

        private readonly FileService _fileService;
        string _connectionString;
        private readonly ExceptionHandler _exceptionHandler;
        private static DbContextOptions<SqlContext> _options;

        public SqlDataProvider(FileService fileService, ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _fileService = fileService;
            //_connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("RemoteDatabase")!;
            _connectionString = Constants.TestDatabaseConnectionString;
            _exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
            _options ??= new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlContext>().UseMySQL(_connectionString).Options;
        }
        public SqlDataProvider(FileService fileService, ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, string connectionString)
        {
            _fileService = fileService;
            _exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _options ??= new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlContext>().UseMySQL(_connectionString).Options;
        }
        public SqlContext GetContext()
        {
            return new SqlContext(_options);
        }

        public IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork(string userId = Constants.DefaultUserId)
        {
            var context = GetContext();
            return new SqlUnitOfWork(context, _fileService, _exceptionHandler, userId!);
        }
```

#### StackTraces

**for "An item has already been added {ConnectionString}"**

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException[T](T key)
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager.d__22.MoveNext()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.d__93.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__70.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__70.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__66.MoveNext()
> at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLRelationalConnection.d__10.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__19.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__21.MoveNext() at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.d__65`1.MoveNext() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
> at chldr_data.remote.Repositories.SqlChangeSetsRepository.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\x.dr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\chldr_data.remote\Repositories\SqlChangeSetsRepository.cs:line 33

**for "Operations that change..." error:**

> at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConcurrentOperationsNotSupported()
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
> at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager.d__22.MoveNext()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.d__93.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__70.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__70.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__66.MoveNext()
> at
> MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLRelationalConnection.d__10.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__19.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__21.MoveNext() at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.d__65`1.MoveNext() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
> at
> chldr_data.remote.Repositories.SqlChangeSetsRepository.d__4.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\Users\x.dr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\chldr_data.remote\Repositories\SqlChangeSetsRepository.cs:line
> 33

Comment: EF is not (and never has been) designed to handle concurrent requests. You need a separate db context for each concurrent operation.

Comment: @StephenCleary each time I create a unitOfWork I create a new Context, and I also tried adding the context with DI and making it Transient - nothing helped

Comment: Did you try using Scoped connection (although theoretically its wrong but for the matter of just checking)
 builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataProvider, SqlDataProvider>();

Comment: @MuhammadSaad yes, I tried.